# jQuery each array

Tags: jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array, each

```
analyse : function (that) {

        var a = new Array();
        var x = 0;

        $(that).children("li").each(function(){
            console.log('test1');
            a[x]['name'] = 'f'; 
            a[x]['link'] = 'UUUUUUUUUUU';
            console.log('test2');
            x++;
        })

        return a;
    }
```

I'm trying to create an array to store the hierarchy from my menu for PHP later on.

The console won't show me "test2", what did I do wrong?

---

Transformed into this with Didier G's Help:

```
analyse : function (that) {
        return $(that).children('li').map(function() {
            var b = {
                name: $(this).children('a').text(), 
                link: $(this).children('a').attr('href')
            };
            if ($(this).children('ul').size() > 0) {
               b.childs =  mcms.module.analyse($(this).children('ul'));
            } 
            return b;
        });
    }
```

So if i say `var y = analyse('#menu');` I get the whole bunch! ^^

Comment: Additionally you shouldn't use `new Array()` but `[]`

Comment: Is it giving you an error in the console?  It seems like `a[x]` is not defined so you're trying to assign a property 'name' to an undefined variable.

Comment: `new Array()` is perfectly fine per the ECMAScript Language Specification and its implementations, but `[]` is shorter and its [reduced compatibility](http://PointedEars.de/es-matrix#features) is hardly relevant today.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`'a[x]'` is undefined at that moment. You have to first build an object and assign it to 'i' position ('x' is indeed a not standard name for an iterator, thanks @Cito):

```
var a = new Array();
var i = 0;

$(that).children("li").each(function(){
        console.log('test1');
        a[i] = { name: 'f', link: 'UUUU' };
        console.log('test2');
        i++;
});
```

Note: your code misses a `;` after the each(). Even though it is valid javascript to omit semi-colons, it is I think better to explicitly use them to avoid misinterpretations.

---

Creating array can be achieve by using [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

```
var a = [];

// .map() returns a jquery array, to obtain a pure javascript array, you must call .toArray() afterwards
a = $(that).children('li').map(function() {
    return { name: 'f', link: 'UUUU' };
}).toArray();
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/LnADu/) to illustrate

This [article](http://encosia.com/use-jquery-to-extract-data-from-html-lists-and-tables/) covers a the use of .each() and .map() for building data collections out of lists in jquery.

Comment: Also, `x` is a poor name for an array index, and the `each()` method already passes an array index to your function so you don't need to maintain your own variable for that. But Didier is right, `map()` is the better solution anyway.

Comment: I totally understand now this is great!!

Comment: Correct is: There is no object yet to have a property `name`. BTW, `b` is unnecessary.  Also, these languages are dynamic, so properties can be added at any time using the property accessor syntax as the OP did (provided the object permits it).  Your `toArray(…)` does nothing useful until the return value is assigned to `a`.

Comment: Initialization `a = []` is pointless here. These languages are loosely typed.  If you must, write `var a = ….toArray();`.

Answer (score 1):

`a` is empty, you are trying to set properties to an undefined object. Use this code instead:

```
    var a = [];
    $(that).children("li").each(function(x){
        console.log('test1');
        a[x] = {};
        a[x].name = 'f'; 
        a[x].link = 'UUUUUUUUUUU';
        console.log('test2');
    })

    return a;
```

Even shorter would be this code (inside the callback):

```
a[x] = {name: 'f', link: 'UUUUUUUUUUU'};
```

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION:** 
I had a similar scenario and was able to come up with a clean solution. I basically had a to make  question object with several questions in them with individual properties.

Here was my solution:

```
$("li").each(function(i,e){
// Build Array
questionOb[i] = {
    'questionSeq' : i, 
    'questionType' : $(this).find(".questionType").attr("rel"), 
    'questionLabel' : $(this).find(".questionLabel").attr("rel"), 
    'questionAnswers' : $(this).find(".questionAnswers").attr("rel"), 
    'questionMinimum' : $(this).find(".questionMinimum").attr("rel"), 
    'questionMaximum' : $(this).find(".questionMaximum").attr("rel"), 
    'questionInterval' : $(this).find(".questionInterval").attr("rel"), 
};
});

var dataString = {
    questionsSet : questionOb
};
```

This essential makes an array of questions for each "li" it finds. The data ends up looking something like this:

```
Array
(
    [questions] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [questionSeq] => 0
                    [questionType] => email
                    [questionLabel] => Please enter your question here.
                    [questionRandom] => no
                    [questionRequired] => no
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [questionSeq] => 1
                    [questionType] => numeric
                    [questionLabel] => Please enter your question here.
                    [questionRandom] => no
                    [questionRequired] => no
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [questionSeq] => 2
                    [questionType] => singleselect
                    [questionLabel] => Please enter your question here.
                    [questionAnswers] => 
                    [questionRandom] => no
                    [questionRequired] => no
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten

```
a[x] = {};
```

to make the element at index `x` (a reference to) an object that can have a properties `p` to be added with

```
a[x][p] = …;
```

You should not use `each(…)`, it is very inefficient by comparison to a `for` loop.

Comment: `.each()`or `.map()` should be used **wisely** is more correct than _you should not use_. For large collections (1000+), it's more efficient to use pure javascript, otherwise, the gain is pretty trivial.

Answer (score 0):

```
a[x] = {name: 'f', link: 'UUUUUUUUUUU'};
```